# How to get Reference to the label in repeater item in code behind

Tags: asp.net, repeater

```
<asp:repeater id="rpt" run="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton id="Delete" runat="server" OnCommand="Delete_Command"></asp:linkButton>
<asp:label id="lblMessage" run="server">
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Delete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgument e)
{

}
```

how i get the reference to the "lblMessage" in Delete_Command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Delete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = (LinkButton)sender;
    Label label = (Label)button.NamingContainer.FindControl("lblMessage");
    // do something with the label
}
```

If you:

1. Have bound the repeater
2. Have ViewState enabled
3. Do not re-bind the repeater earlier in the post back

this should work. If not, please verify that the id of the label is indeed exactly the same as in the `...FindControl("lblMessage");`. Also make sure that `runat="server"` is set on all the controls involved.

**Edit**: One more thing to check: Search the markup file (the .aspx file) and check if there are any other controls that *also* use the same event in the code behind. If another control is using the same event handler and that control is not in the repeater, the label will not be found.

Comment: NamingContainer.FindControl("lblMessage") return null

Comment: @AbdulBasit Correct the label. It should have `runat="server"`, not `run="server"`.

Comment: @AbdulBasit Have you bound the repeater? And do you have ViewState enabled?

Comment: every thing is same as you describe above.. except the visible property set to "false", and i don't think so this create any problem.

Comment: @AbdulBasit I think you will have to paste in some more code. The actual code for: *1) The markup for the repeater* and *2) The code where the repeater is bound*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33131/discussion-between-abdul-basit-and-user1429080)

Answer (score 0):

means are you want find a lable in Delete_Command event?

in aspx

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" OnCommand="Delete_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" run="server">
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in aspx.cs

```
 protected void Delete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
        {
            Label lblMessage = item.FindControl("lblMessage") as Label;
            if (lblMessage != null)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you technique is matching with every Label in the repeater Itemtemplate. what i want is lblMessage to the specific item.

Comment: >>matching every label
as you add items to the repeater use int i=count; i++ as you add and use i.tosting to change the label id to get a unique label id

Answer (score 0):

If You want to make it in your way use following code in

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

             (((LinkButton)source).NamingContainer).FindControl("lblName")

        }
```

Another approach.. But something that you can buy

aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%=Eval("Name") %>' ></asp:Label>
      <asp:LinkButton runat="server"  CommandName="Delete_Command" Text="sd"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

.cs

```
 protected void Delete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgument e)
    {
          if(e.CommandName != null)// Conditional Check
          {    
               Label label = e.Item.FindControl("lblMessage");
               // do something with the label
          }
   }
```

Comment: i don't think so the CommandEventArgument e has a Item Property.

Comment: Make it RepeaterCommandEventArgs and it will work.. As your parent source of event is repeater

Comment: if it set to be RepeaterCommandEventArgs then the handler does not match.

Comment: Yes offcourse it will work Repeater has CommandEvent of delegate type that consumes **RepeaterCommandEventArgs**

Comment: No overload for 'Delete_Command' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventHandler'

Comment: Ohh man I stucked ... Remove OnCommand from link button and use onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" in repeater tag...

Comment: This is not the repeaterItemCommand Event. this is CommandButton event in which i want the Label control. your are confusing it

Comment: this is not the case which i needed.