# How to get a reference to a label in a Repeater control in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:repeater id="rpt" run="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton id="Delete" runat="server" OnCommand="Delete_Command"></asp:linkButton>
<asp:label id="lblMessage" run="server">
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Delete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgument e)
{

}
```

How can I get a reference to the "lblMessage" in Delete_Command?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1150079.aspx/1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Reference to the label in repeter item in code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541206/how-to-get-reference-to-the-label-in-repeter-item-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reorganize your code a little bit, which will allow you to perform such operations easily using `FindControl`. Basically my suggestion boils down to handling Command event not of the link button, but of the repeater itself:

```
<asp:repeater id="rpt" run="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand">
```

Then access to item contents is extremely easy:

```
protected void rpt_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label label = e.Item.FindControl("lblMessage");
    LinkButton linkButton = e.Item.FindControl("Delete");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

Page :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void rpt_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        Label lblMessage = e.Item.FindControl("lblMessage") as Label;
    }
}
```